# Reload circle comes down too far

Tags: bug, android-app

When pulling down from the main feed user interface element in the beta android app, the material design circle pulls down twice the distance as normal apps.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the circular refresh icon, when pulled, goes much too far down:

> [image: Screenshot]

I am running Touchwiz Android 4.4.2 (Rooted) on a Samsung Galaxy Avant.